# How to fix this "Unhandled rejection TypeError: res.xls is not a function"

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, xls

I'm getting 'res.xls is not a function', I've installed all required packages but not able to resolve. I want to convert json array to xls file.

I'm using node.js with MySql.

I've route

router.get('/convert', controller.convert)

And my controller is:

```
    const express = require('express'); 
       const router = module.exports = express.Router(); 
       const json2xls = require('json2xls'); 
       router.use(json2xls.middleware);
    module.exports = {
        convert: convert (req, res) => {
        var contacts = [{
                        name: 'Bob',
                        lastName: 'Smith'
                    }, {
                        name: 'James',
                        lastname: 'David'
                    }];
            res.xls('report.xlsx', contacts);
        }
};
```

I expect JSON data should be converted into xls file.

Comment: why are you attempting to call middleware yourself instead of defining an express route?

Comment: Please do check https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2xls

Comment: I did.  you're not calling `json2xls`.  instead you're registering it as express middleware, then calling that middleware function yourself inside the `convert` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was calling it in controller rather than route.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.It may help you.

```
var express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();
const json2xls = require('json2xls');
router.use(json2xls.middleware);

app.use('/', router);
function convert(req, res) {
    console.log('dad')
    var contacts = [{
        name: 'Bob',
        lastName: 'Smith'
    }, {
        name: 'James',
        lastname: 'David'
    }];
    res.xls('report.xlsx', contacts);
}

router.get('/convert', convert.bind(this));
app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Server Now Running On localhost:4000'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    app.get('/',function(req, res) {
var contacts = [{
                    name: 'Bob',
                    lastName: 'Smith'
                }, {
                    name: 'James',
                    lastname: 'David'
                }];
        res.xls('report.xlsx', contacts);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but that was my controller and I've different route.